# Why doesn't my tkinter window show my panel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I've got the following code:

```
import tkinter
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading


class HudGui:
    def __init__(self, window):
        # defining everything for video capture and the tkinter window
    self.CapDev= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.cams = []
    self.counter = 0
    self.frame = None
    self.panel = None
    self.wind = window

    btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Snapshot!")
    btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)

    # defining threading for video stream
    self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.videoLoop(), args=(1,))
    self.thread.start()

def videoLoop(self):
    while not self.stopEvent.is_set():

        # reading and modifying the frame to have the proper data type
        self.frame = self.CapDev.read()[1]
        image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        if self.panel is None:
            self.panel = tkinter.Label(image=image)
            self.panel.image = image
            self.panel.pack(side="left")   # side="left", padx=10, pady=10

            # otherwise, update the panel
        else:
            self.panel.configure(image=image)
            self.panel.image = image


hud = tkinter.Tk()
hud.title("HUD")

HudGui(hud)

hud.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. I get no window but I do know it is updating the panel (I've tested it with printing messages). Could there be permissions problem for accessing the camera and things like that?

**Project info:**

Python = 3.7.3

opencv-contrib-python = 3.4.4.19

Comment: You have indentation errors in `__init__`. This `target=self.videoLoop()` should read `target=self.videoLoop, ...`. Creating a widget, `tkinter.Label(...`, inside a `Thread` is error prone. You have to do it in `__init__`.

Comment: changing `self.videoLoop()` to `self.videoLoop` solved the problem. About the label in the loop: it only gets created if there is none, otherwise only it's contents are modified

Comment: ***"it only gets created if there is none"***: That's not the problem, creating a GUI widget in a `Thread` is **Error prone**. You can do: `self.panel = tkinter.Label(image=None)` in `__init__`

Comment: I don't know how it could cause any problems but I changed it and it still works so thanks for the help!